# How to manage multiple UIViewController from one Container?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview, uibuilder

I have a `UIViewController` inside which I have a Container.  I want to be able to change the `UIViewController` inside that Container.  I think I can manage the Segue calls to make that happen but how do I connect multiple `UIViewController` objects (and their related Segues) on a Storyboard with UIBUilder?

[image]

Here you can see my basic layout and that I've attached one `UIViewController` to the Container.  Now I want to attach the second to it on the Storyboard in the same way and manage both in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
RowViewController *infoController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RowViewController"];
[self addChildViewController:infoController];
infoController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 86, 745, 682);
[self.view addSubview:infoController.view];
[infoController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: So there's no way to connect it *on the Storyboard*?